# Show Dialog From Subclass

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to open a dialog from a subclass.
However, there are some problems with the Show function.
It does not take the subclass but the main class.

The Main Controller :

```
    

    private void InitNavigation(){
        MenuView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        NavController navCo = navHostFragment.getNavController();

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.home2,
                R.id.verantstaltung, R.id.veranstalter,R.id.tanzpartnersuche).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navCo, appBarConfiguration);

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(MenuView, navCo);

        navCo.navigate(R.id.home2);
    }
```

I think at the Funktion openDatePickerDialog is the error. With getActivity().getsupportFragmentManager i get the Main Class but here i will get the subclass
The Sub Controller from which the dialog should be opened :

```
    private void openDatePickerDialog(String type){
        new DialogDatePicker(type).show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"DialogDatePicker");
    }

   
}
```

And Last the Dialog Controller :

```
package florian.tanzapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CalendarView;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;

public class DialogDatePicker extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    private DialogDatePickerListener listener;
    //DatePicker
    CalendarView DatePicker;

    //Var
    String Type;
    Date datum;

    public  DialogDatePicker(String type){
        Type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_datepicker,null);

        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("DatePicker")
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        listener.applyDate(datum,Type);
                    }
                });

        DatePicker = view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView3);
        DatePicker.setMinDate((new Date().getTime()));
        DatePicker.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                datum = newDate.getTime();

            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context){
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            listener = (DialogDatePickerListener) context;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement DialogDatePickerListener");
        }
    }

    public interface DialogDatePickerListener{
        void applyDate(Date datum, String type);
    }
}
```

I don't have so much experience in Java because I am more specialized in C#. Does anyone see the problem what is wrong when I want to open the dialog from the subclasse ?

Comment: can you be more precise and more clear in what dialog, where and when it's supposed to open, and what you mean by 'want to open the dialog from the subclass'? do you want it to be opened from within code in the subclass, or do you mean to open a dialog that is created within the subclass? Also, what subclass and parent are you referring to?

Comment: The dialog is to be opened from the fragment class. When the dialog is closed, the fragment class should receive the result. But in my code it is so that the mainactivity class in which the fragment is loaded gets the answer. But this should not be so

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).